# Special characters in Jekyll generated HTML breaking RSS feed. Any fixes?

Tags: ruby, xml, rss, jekyll

I have this line of text in one of my Jekyll generated blog posts:

```
Welcome, AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBB+b��C BBBBBBBBBBBBBB+b��C
```

Apparently though, the `�` breaks my RSS feed which is generated with the following code:

```
---
layout: none
---
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:lang="en">
<title type="text">{{ site.title }}</title>
<generator uri="https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll">Jekyll</generator>
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="{{ site.url }}/feed.xml" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="{{ site.url }}" />
<updated>{{ site.time | date_to_xmlschema }}</updated>
<id>{{ site.url }}/</id>
<author>
  <name>{{ site.owner.name }}</name>
  <uri>{{ site.url }}/</uri>
  <email>{{ site.owner.email }}</email>
</author>
{% for post in site.posts limit:20 %}

<entry>
  <title type="html"><![CDATA[{{ post.title | cdata_escape }}]]></title>
  <link>{% if post.link %}{{ post.link }}{% else %}{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}{% endif %}</link>
  <id>{{ site.url }}{{ post.id }}</id>
  {% if post.modified %}<updated>{{ post.modified | to_xmlschema }}T00:00:00-00:00</updated>
  <published>{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}</published>
  {% else %}<published>{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}</published>
  <updated>{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}</updated>{% endif %}
  <author>
    <name>{{ site.owner.name }}</name>
    <uri>{{ site.url }}</uri>
    <email>{{ site.owner.email }}</email>
  </author>
  <content type="html">{{ post.content | xml_escape }}
  &lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}&quot;&gt;{{ post.title }}&lt;/a&gt; was originally published by {{ site.owner.name }} at &lt;a href=&quot;{{ site.url }}&quot;&gt;{{ site.title }}&lt;/a&gt; on {{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}.&lt;/p&gt;</content>
</entry>
{% endfor %}
</feed>
```

Accessing the feed throws the following error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 392 at column 104: PCDATA invalid Char value 24
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Generating a feed isn't hard, and there are multiple gems out there to do so, using RSS or ATOM. It looks like your content isn't being encoded correctly, which is the reason for using one of the pre-built "wheels".

Comment: @theTinMan The code to generate the feed is from the theme I'm using.

Comment: Time to submit a pull request to that theme, I guess.